# In the time of Ramayana & Mahabharata, which gods were worshipped outside India?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, history

Ramayana and Mahabharatha happened Before Christ. We are aware of Ramayana & Mahabharatha happened in Hindu Land. But i wonder what about the rest of the population in the world at that time. Whether there were people existing in the globe, rest of Asia like in European countries? If they did exist, who was their GOD and whom were they following?

Comment: may be they were not civilized :-) and searching who am i?....

Comment: Does this belong to history.stackexchange.com than hinduism.SE?

Comment: see - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18006/why-hinduism-did-not-get-propagated-to-entire-world/18014#18014

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt to answer. Note: the following content is based on searches on internet so correction may be need or the content may be all wrong. But I thing it is better with incorrect sources than nothing, so someone in future will correct it.

While searching for timeline of Ramayana as per [Dr. Vartak](https://web.archive.org/web/20150924030215/http://www.hindunet.org/hindu_history/ancient/ramayan/rama_vartak.html) the time period of Ramayana at least 9000 years ago so that means some time around 7000 BC.

Now we know that some of the old cultures in the world are Egypt, Greece, Iran. While search for Greece I [found that](http://www.in2greece.com/english/historymyth/ancient_hist_and_myth.htm) the Neolithic period dated approximately 7,000 - 3,000 B.C. So we can safely say, that was a start time of human civilization coming in shape so it may be a case that people were not doing any type of worship of god.

Answer (score 1):

1. Question is interesting and hypothetical
2. India appears to be the only country which had continuous human habitants
3. The only reason could be only those law & god abiding shall surive holocaust written in every religious scriptures
4. While excavations & studies are being done in western sphere, think it is
   directioinless, luckless, and difficult to find any answer to your question
   raised.

Answer (score 0):

It must be Solar or [Sun God Worship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_deity) that might have prevalent in the ancient world.

1. Sanatana Dharma aka Hinduism : It is self explanatory that people in the land of India used to worship Sun.  The Sun God was eulogised in Rig Veda. Savitr or Gayatri mantra is being recited in this land since long. Even in [Shanmata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanmata) ( 6 ways of Worship), worship of Surya was included.
2. Africa , China, Indonasia, etc have practised Sun Worship.