# How has Hinduism spread & existing in Russia?

Tags: krishna, history, culture, vedic-rituals, iskcon

Russia & nearby countries were part of communist USSR for a while, which was typically anti-religion.

Yet there are several [Hindu Russians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinduism_in_Russia) (0.1% of population). How did it spread in such remote country? Is ISKCON solely responsible or were there traces before as well?

Extra Qn: In what state is it today?

Comment: This is more related to History.SE than here.

Comment: In Ramayana, Bharatha's wife hailed form Kekeya desha which is in Russia (probably kazhakstan, going linguistically). sanatana dharma was prevalent everywhere, and slowly degraded over time. always it's the epicentre that degrades the last, that's why other nations are more materialistic - more detailed answer here - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18006/why-hinduism-did-not-get-propagated-to-entire-world/18014#18014

Comment: I think having a tag for an organisation is not good. If a question is asked about ISKCON, it is good to tag about the content in the question rather than the organisation itself. This tag has been deleted several times in the past.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, if the tag is naturally deleted, then I am fine. But if you read the wiki article, then ISKCON has a great impact on spread of Hinduism in Russia. Hence, I have mentioned it. It's difficult to find ISKCON specific questions anyways, let this contribute to it. :-)