# Was sanatan dharma only religion until kalyug?

Tags: dwapara-yuga

i was confused if sanatan dharma was only religion until dwaparyug. Did all other countries like mesopotamia and egypt came in kalyug?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why didn't Hinduism get propagated to the entire world?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18006/why-didnt-hinduism-get-propagated-to-the-entire-world)